# Font characters messed up when zooming out

Tags: css, fonts, cross-browser, font-face

I'm using Proxima Novia font type for a mega menu, in different weights.

I have a problem with the bold font weight when I zoom out some characters will be messed up. For example, when zooming out the dot on the (i)letter will disappear and the Letter will look like (l) Letter in lowercase.

Any idea how to solve this problem? is it related to browser setting or font type issue?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Why are you zooming the browser?

Comment: Maybe you included only the regular font type without the bold type? That's an issue in some cases because if bold type is missing browsers try to imitate it what looks sometimes ugly. It would help if you provide an example (fiddle) and name your browser.

Comment: Will, I can't get rid of the bold weight. regarding browsers, it makes no difference all browsers have this problem when zooming out.

Comment: hey mate have same issue how did u solved it?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, what font-size are you using? You can use relative font size such as vw,vh so that font size changes according to view port.

Comment: provide your code so that we can understand your problem,thanks.